# Spring Boot controller test loading entire application context

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

Spring Boot here. I currently have the following REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class FizzbuzzController {

    private final FizzbuzzService FizzbuzzService;

    public FizzbuzzController(FizzbuzzService FizzbuzzService) {
        this.FizzbuzzService = FizzbuzzService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/Fizzbuzzs/{fizzbuzzId}")
    public ResponseEntity<FizzbuzzDTO> addFizzbuzz(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files,
                                      @PathVariable String fizzbuzzId) throws IOException {

        FizzbuzzDTO fizzbuzzDTO = fizzbuzzService.store(files, fizzbuzzId);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(fizzbuzzDTO);
        
    }

}
```

I would like to write an integration test for it that:

1. Mocks or stubs an HTTP request to the URL; and
2. Allows me to inject the `FizzbuzzController` (under test) with a mocked `FizzbuzzService` or the real thing; and
3. Allows me to inspect the HTTP response coming back from the method (check status code, check response entity, etc.)

My best attempt thus far:

```
@WebMvcTest(FizzbuzzController.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class FizzbuzzControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private FizzbuzzService FizzbuzzService;

    @Test
    public void should_store_fizzbuzz_files() throws Exception {
        // I can't even get the test to run
        assertTrue(1 == 1);
    }

}
```

When I run this, the test fails to run and it is clear (looking at the logs) that Spring is loading the entire application context of my app, whereas I just want it to isolate the context to this test class, the main `FizzbuzzController` class, and anything in the dependency tree underneath it.

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another context for testing. I'm suggesting you to have a separate Test config:

```
@TestConfiguration
@Slf4j
@EnableJpaRepositories("tth.patientportal.repository")
public class TestConfig { // bean configs goes here for testing if you need to change 
  // context}
```

and in a controller test build the context like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-unittest.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})    
public class RestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() 
    {
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.
            webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnRegisteredUser() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.
            perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .post("url")                        
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.username").exists());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Shamitha (+1) -- quick question, what does `@EnableJpaRepositories("...")` do?

Comment: That's for when you use jpa repositories, I bet you are going to need them